# Deriving the distribution of the sum of censored variables

Tags: distributions, censoring

I want to be able to calculate the distribution of 
$$Y = \sum_{i=1}^n\max\{0,X_i\}$$
where the random variable $X_i\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$.  Is the calculation of $f_Y(y)$ possible and if so what is it?

Answer (score 3):

The distribution is of mixed type (it's neither discrete nor continuous) and has neither a density nor probability mass function.

However, it is a [mixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures) of a (degenerate) discrete and a continuous distribution.

It should be possible to compute the CDF for small $n$; its just a sum over cases where 0,1,2,...,$n$ of the $X$ values are <0; the number of terms to account for grows very rapidly with $n$, though.

$Y$ takes the value $0$ with probability $\prod_i F_{X_i}(0)$ and otherwise it's from a truncated-distribution based on the distribution of the $X's$. But it's going to be complicated to do exactly.

With middling to large $n$ I'd actually be inclined to use simulation on the continuous part (perhaps with smoothing by logspline density estimation).

With very large $n$ it may even be possible to come up with some kind of approximation.

What do you need it for?

Comment: Research problem in optimization.