# Rectifier function of random variable

Tags: random-variable, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Let $X$ be a random variable with distribution $F_X$ and density $f_X$.  Define 
$$g(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    x & : x \ge 0\\
   0 & : x < 0
  \end{array}
\right\}$$

and let $Y=g(X)$.  What is the PDF of $Y$?

**My approach:** via CDF

$$F_Y(y) = \Pr(Y\le y) = \Pr(g(X)\le y) = \Pr(X\le y) = F_X(y), \ y\ge 0$$

After taking the derivative,

$$f_Y(y) = f_X(y), \ y \ge 0$$

This seems to be incorrect because $f_Y(y)$ is  not a PDF (integral is not equal to one).

I know that it probably has to do something with the fact that all $x\lt 0$ are mapped onto $y=0$.

I just don't know how I can incorporate this in a constructive way.

Comment: Although you define $g$ specifically, you replace it with a *different* definition in your calculations: that's where things go wrong.  Regardless, there's a fundamental problem with this question: if $X$ has any chance of being negative, then $Y$ does not have a PDF.  Also, why do you keep writing "$y=0\ldots 1$"? That isn't part of any explicit definition or assumption.

Comment: @whuber Good you noticed, that was an error in my notes.  Isn't there a way to do something with dirac delta perhaps?

Comment: Yes, there is, provided you accept such generalized functions as being acceptable PDFs. In your newly edited version I see no errors: your calculation simply is incomplete.  What value would you give to $F_Y$ for *negative* arguments?

Comment: @whuber   Using intuition. $F_Y(y) = F_X(0) Heaviside(y) + (F_X(y)-F_X(0))$. This would give $f_Y (y) = F_X(0)\delta(y) + f_X(y)$. However, I have learned that my intuition is often wrong in this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that $X$ is a continuous random variable. Then, around variables like $Y$ there are two possible confusions related to terminology:

$Y$ is a *censored* version of $X$ (and sometimes people confuse "[censoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_%28statistics%29)" with "[truncating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_%28statistics%29)"). Also, $Y$ has a *mixed* distribution (and sometimes people confuse "[mixed](http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/Mixed.html)" distributions with "[mixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution)" distributions).

$Y$ is a censored version of $X$ because a) we observe only non-negative values and b) when we observe $0$ we only know that the corresponding realization of $X$ was $x\leq 0$, i.e. we learn only that $X$ fell in an interval, not its specific value. This also creates the mixed distribution, i.e. a distribution that has a discrete part and a continuous part:

At value $0$, non-zero probability mass concentrates, equal to $P(X\leq 0)$. For $X>0$ we have $Y=X$. So the CDF of Y is

$$F_Y(y)  = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    F_X(y)& : y > 0\\
   F_X(0) & : y = 0\\
   0 & \text{elsewhere}
  \end{array}
\right\}$$

and $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}F_Y(y)=1$.

As for its probability -mass function? - density function? -well, see the illuminating and educative comments below on the matter, as well as ways to express it in one row. Let's say we have a point where non-zero probability mass concentrates, $P(Y=0) = P(X \leq 0)<1$, while for $y>0$ we have a continuous function $f_X(y)$ that does satisfy $\int_{0}^{\infty}f_X(y)dy = 1- P(X \leq 0)$ , while this entity is $0$ everywhere else. So in all, it sums up to unity.

Comment: I was unfamiliar with the concept of mixed distributions. This helped me a lot and gives a constructive way of deriving the PDF. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. The following post shows how nevertheless, mixed distributions still can behave obediently asymptotically: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95214/if-z-i-min-k-i-x-i-x-i-sim-ua-i-b-i-what-is-the-distribution-of

Comment: (1) To be complete, you need to stipulate the values of $F_Y$ and $f_y$ for negative arguments. (2) Exactly how would you use an indicator to write $f_Y$?

Comment: @whuber Since by construction $Y \in [0,\infty]$ I have difficulty understanding why we should stipulate values for negative arguments. As for indicator functions, I do not have anything more to mind than something like $$f_Y(y) = f_X(y)\cdot (1-I_{\{Y=0\}}) + P(X\leq 0) \cdot (I_{\{Y=0\}})$$, or the other way around.

Comment: Normally I would not insist on the point about covering the case $y\lt 0$, Alecos, but this is precisely the issue that was causing the OP grief, so I thought that dealing with it explicitly would be helpful in this instance.  As far as the indicator goes, your proposal doesn't work (even after replacing the "$Y$" by "$y$" in the formula so it makes sense). In order to use such notation you first have to expand the concept of a PDF to cover discrete measures, so you might as well write $f_Y$ explicitly as a measure, as in $$f_X(y)I(y\ge 0)dy+F_X(0)d\delta_0$$ where $\delta_0(A)=I(0\in A).$

Comment: @whuber I will happily delete my reference to indicator functions. As for the non-existent case of $y<0$, well, why not?

Comment: The CDF is discontinuous at $0$ and so not even giving a hint about this (as in earlier versions of this answer) was certainly not a good idea, as whuber pointed out. While this has been corrected, the pdf is still incorrect. The value of $f_Y$ at $0$ is _not_ $P\{X \leq 0\}$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Isn't $P(Y=0) = P(X\leq 0)$?

Comment: Yes, $P(Y=0)=P(X\leq 0)$ but that is _not_ the value of the density function of $Y$ at $0$. Suppose we are given that $$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}0.9,&0<y<1,\\0.1,&y=0,\\0.1,&y=1,\\0.1,&y=2.\end{cases}$$ Since the value of a _density_ function at one point has no effect on probability calculations (in fact, two density functions are regarded as _equivalent_ if they differ only on a set of measure $0$), how can we tell if the probability mass is at $0$ or $1$ or at $2$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I prefer to have symbols on both sides of the $=$ symbol. I have explicitly written "the hybrid probability mass/density function is...", and so the symbol $f_Y(y)$ does not denote a density function but it is generic for this hybrid entity which is a probability mass function when $Y=0$ and a probability density function when $Y>0$. I am not saying this is established notation, but as I said, I prefer to have a symbol for anything -and to the degree that it is explicitly defined I do not see any problem with such a notational approach.

Comment: Alecos, the two problems with your notation are that it is ambiguous and that when interpreted conventionally--as @Dilip has explained--it does not give a valid PDF: when your $f_Y$ is integrated over $\mathbb{R}$ it results in a value of $1-\Pr(X\le 0)$ rather than $1$. To be clear, your notation *must* distinguish between functional values and measures.

Comment: @whuber So how could one write this entity using branches? Or it cannot be consistently written in such a way?

Comment: It would be unusual to try to write $f_Y$ in that way, Alecos. These hybrid discrete-continuous distributions are usually expressed as *mixtures* of a discrete and continuous distribution. Thus you might define the continuous part of the measure as $g(y)=f_X(y),\ y\ge 0;\ g(y)=0,\ y\lt 0$ and the discrete part (an atom at $0$ of size $F_X(0)$--let's call it $\mu$) in any way you find appropriate for discrete measures, so that $f_Y(y)=g(y)dy+\mu$. This notation makes it clear that $f_Y$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure $dy$.

Comment: @whuber. Thanks, that settles it for me. I adjusted my answer.